# Sidekid dynamic queue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, worker

i would like to know if someone manage to dynamically reassign queue in sidekiq client middleware.
I need to implement a custom method to route worker to different queue if some conditions are meet.

in my middleware i tried to override queue value but not working

module Sidekiq::Middleware::Client
  class Dispatcher

```
def call(worker_class, job, queue, redis_pool)
  queue = "crawl"
  job["queue"] = "crawl"
  yield
end
```

end
end

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Can you show the other part of the configuration?
The following configuration worked for me.

```
class QueueOverrideMiddleware
  def call(worker_class, job, queue, redis_pool)
    job["queue"] = "your_new_queue"
    yield
  end
end

Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  config.client_middleware do |chain|
    chain.add QueueOverrideMiddleware
  end
end
```